# How do I show a loading bar in a UIWebview when a page is loading?

Tags: uiwebview, uiprogressview

I've put the Progress View at the top of my webView, and I guess now I just need to link it to the loading of the page? How do I do this? I'm new to objective c.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from this 3rd party:
https://github.com/ninjinkun/NJKWebViewProgress